# Change accessibility in Runtime

Tags: java

As mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6):

*"accessibility is a static property that can be determined at **compile time**; it depends only on types and declaration modifiers."*

In this case, what does `java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(boolean)` function really do in **runtime**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setAccessible` **does not alter the accessibility level of a member**. It only allows a certain member to be accessed **through reflection alone**. This doesn't explicitly break the rules of accessibility, since your code doesn't really access the member: it **invokes a Reflection method** that internally does some magic, accessing the member on your behalf.

With this in mind there is also a crucial point to note: Java also has a very powerful and unpenetrable security system that can deny the usage of reflection to foreign code. Whenever needed, this mechanism can be used to truly prevent access to private members.

Comment: This is correct due to the way reflection works.  But thats more of a side effect of the API than a hard truth.  And lets face it a hack on SUNs part.

Comment: @stackmonster I'm glad such hacks exist, though, because they allow many important techniques that reduce boilerplate. Java is such a language (a **blue-collar** language, as pitched by James Gosling) that has quite a limited set of first-class features and many backdoor APIs to cover for that. It separates the idioms meant for client code from idioms meant only for experienced library/framework writers.

Answer (score 1):

I lets you change the accessibility of the object using reflection, just as you expect it. From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject%5B%5D,%20boolean%29) of class `AccessibleObject`:

> Setting the accessible flag in a reflected object permits sophisticated applications with sufficient privilege, such as Java Object Serialization or other persistence mechanisms, to manipulate objects in a manner that would normally be prohibited.

Answer (score 1):

Your quote does not apply to the reflection API. The [JLS #1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-1.html#jls-1.4) explicitly states that you can achieve via reflection operations not explicitly authorised by the JLS:

> Consequently, this specification does not describe reflection in any detail. Many linguistic constructs have analogs in the reflection API, but these are generally not discussed here. So, for example, when we list the ways in which an object can be created, we generally do not include the ways in which the reflective API can accomplish this. Readers should be aware of these additional mechanisms even though they are not mentioned in this text.